How should I make my C++ code built using Xcode on M1 run on M3?
I have built and compiled a C++ code using Xcode from a MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Pro with the following Build Settings:

Architecture: Arm64; x86_64;
macOS Deployment Target: macOS 12.0 or 14.0

My code runs on both M1 and M2, but for some reason it doesn't run on M3.
How do I ensure that my C++ code can run on M1, M2, and M3?
target Build Settings:

Architecture: Arm64; x86_64;
macOS Deployment Target: macOS 12.0 or 14.0

I'm expecting the my code will run on M1, M2, and M3?
But, I'm getting "The application can't be opened" on a MacBook Pro with Apple M3 Pro Apple M3 Max.

Nothing to do with the cpu. You need to notice notarize applications to run them on machines other than the one you compiled then on
